# How to get QTreeWidget item's text, when a checkbox within is toggled?

Tags: python, pyside2, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem, qcheckbox

I've made a QTreeWidget that has a number of rows, each row with a text item, and a checkbox.  How do I get the text, when the checkbox is toggled?  I know that I can use currentItem() to get the currently selected TreeWidgetItem, but the row isn't necessarily selected.  And I can't use the QTreeWidget's itemClicked/itemPressed signals, as they don't seem to emit when a checkbox widget within it is clicked.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class TestUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestUI, self).__init__()
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.setHeaderLabels(('text', 'checkbox'))
        for x in range(0, 3):
            item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
            item.setText(0, str(x))
            checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(parent=self.tree)
            checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkbox_toggled)
            self.tree.setItemWidget(item, 1, checkbox)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tree)
    
    def checkbox_toggled(self):
        print 'The text of the checkbox TreeWidgetItem is...'
        print None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        ui.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass
    ui = TestUI()
    ui.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution involves obtaining the QTreeWidgetItem to which the QCheckBox belongs, so a possible solution is to use the position of the pressed QCheckbox since it is a child of the viewport so the item can be obtained using the indexAt() method. To get the QCheckbox in the slot you can use the sender() method:

```py
class TestUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestUI, self).__init__()
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.setHeaderLabels(("text", "checkbox"))
        for x in range(0, 3):
            item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
            item.setText(0, str(x))
            checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
            checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkbox_toggled)
            self.tree.setItemWidget(item, 1, checkbox)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tree)

    def checkbox_toggled(self):
        checkbox = self.sender()
        print("sender: {}".format(checkbox))
        if checkbox is None:
            return
        item = self.tree.itemAt(checkbox.pos())
        if item is not None:
            print("The text of the checkbox TreeWidgetItem is {}".format(item.text(0)))
```